# I cannot vote to close questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting-to-close

This evening I was trying to close a question, and I noticed I could not. All the times I paste the question ID in the text area, the browser tries to load the previous of the question, but it fails. Since the preview is not shown, the button to vote to close is not enabled.

[image: screenshot]

I tried also pasting the question URL, but that didn't change anything.

I then tried on *Meta Stack Overflow*, and I close vote to close a question. First I tried with https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165895/stackoverflow-and-swearing, and then with [Are revenge (non serial) down votes allowed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165896/are-revenge-non-serial-down-votes-allowed) (without effectively voting to close it).

In the first case, the vote was successfully registered, and I was the first one to vote to close it. (The comment about the duplicate question has my username.)

[image: screenshot]

In the second case, the question preview was shown, and I could click on the button to vote.

[image: screenshot]

As far as I can see, the only difference is that on *Meta Stack Overflow*, for the questions for which the closing dialog box was shown, I got a list of question.

[image: screenshot]

That doesn't happen on *Drupal Answers*.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: So is it the same bug as [Cannot vote to close as duplicate in Chrome](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165828) ?

Comment: @Gilles It is the same report, except that on Drupal Answers I tried with Google Chrome, Safari, and Firefox. It seems it doesn't work on the site where I am moderator, but it works on other sites. (Well, at least I tested it on two sites.)

Comment: It's not a browser bug, kiamlaluno @Gilles. But yes, it's the same bug.